# filter high frequencies in time series data - python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I  have the following csv file containing data from electrophysiology. The third column contains filtered data using a software. The second column contains the non-filtered data.

```
data = pd.read_csv("trial_filtered.csv")
datad = np.asarray(data)

x1 = datad[:100,0]
y1 = datad[:100,1]
y2 = datad[:100, 2]
```

I want to plot this data and compare filtered from non-filtered.

```
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'yo-')
plt.title('BB565 - OD')      
plt.ylabel('raw signal (voltage)')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(x1, y2, 'r.-')
plt.xlabel('time (milliseconds)')
plt.ylabel('filtered data')

plt.show()
```

In addition I would like to filter out everything above 40Hz for the second column and then create an additional column.

I have tried the following but I keep getting stuck. Is there another way to filter out high frequencies from my time series data without using the nitime module?

```
y3 = []
ts_y1 = nitime.TimeSeries(y1, time_unit='ms', sampling_interval=1.0)
#let's take out everything above 30 hertz
filter = nitime.analysis.FilterAnalyzer(ts_y1, lb=0., ub=40.)
filtered_ts = filter.fir.datad
y3.append(filtered_ts.copy())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display all the series in a single graph, 
you can use plt.plot() calls successively,
and finally ending it with a plt.show(), this will put all of them in a single figure.

For your second question, if you want a "hard" filter, you can try using the FFT modules as follows :

1. FFT the signal, and figure out the equivalent angular frequency for 30Hz,
2. Locate the bin, and set all the bins above that frequency to zero. (remember to use fftshift before doing this)
3. Do an ifft, and you have a low pass filtered signal. I will write a small script to illustrate and upload it here soon.

I hope this helps!